# Using a C++ proxy dll for DirectX9, how would one rotate a scene?

Tags: c++, dll, proxy, directx

I'm looking to add free-look to a DirectX 9 game (even when the game disables it) via a proxy d3d9.dll. I have the source code to a simple proxy in C++. The game itself is not open-source, but the developers couldn't care less about mods.

I know it is possible, because some 3D anaglpyh driver hacks that use proxy dlls (like IZ3D) rotate the scene quite a bit when the distance between the two eyes is set to very high. Code for this effect on the web (at least, using Google) simply does not exist. Keep in mind that the game uses shaders and makes no obvious use of the matrix stack.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general terms, most 3D shaders use a set of three matrices to determine how vertices are transformed into screen space. In DirectX, these are commonly called the World, View and Projection matrices (in GL, the 'World' matrix is commonly referred to as 'Model'). In D3D9, these matrices will be set as shader constants (via IDirect3DDevice9::SetVertexShaderConstantF). Also note that is it is common practice to concatenate these matrices into a single matrix on the CPU before passing them to the vertex shader, so that the redundant calculation is not being performed per-vertex.

Assuming this is the setup of the shaders in the game you are trying to proxy, you would need to identify which shaders to target (eg. which ones are 3D world-object shaders). Note that there may be shaders in the game which are not for 3D world rendering, such as those for UI (if applicable). Then, intercept any calls to IDirect3DDevice9::SetVertexShaderConstantF when the targeted shaders are active, and modify the uniform(s) associated with transforming the vertices to screen space. This will take some trial and error, and certainly, some knowledge of HLSL disassembly, as I'm assuming you don't have the source for the shaders.

Even accomplishing that, it's very likely that you will not get the results you want, if you plan to modify the 'View' portion of the transformation in any significant way (eg. where the camera is looking). The reason being is that frequently, many game systems perform 3D world calculations on the CPU, which you would obviously not be affecting. The most obvious example is a frustum based culling system, which determines which objects to render. Because proxying will not modify such a system, you may "look off into empty space".

Comment: Broad questions require broad answers. I think this is just what I was looking for! Since I'm new to the site, how do I mark your answer as the one I wanted?

Comment: Glad it helps! To accept, click the checkbox right underneath the voting buttons next to the answer.